# Таймер на форме, обратный отсчет времени

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме существует 32 `label` они обновляются раз в секунду при помощи события `timer_tick`

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime current_time = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < allDocs.Count; i++)
    {
        if (null != allDocs[i].StartTimeFormLastAction)
        {
            allDocs[i].ToUpdateTimer(current_time - (DateTime)allDocs[i].StartTimeFormLastAction);
        }
    }

}
```

Ниже метод, который инициализирует новое значения в свойство `Text` `label`

```
public void ToUpdateTimer(TimeSpan newTime)
{
    time.Text = String.Format("{0}", newTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
}
```

Проблема в мерцании, ничего не могу поделать, конечные пользователи еще не жаловались, но меня дико раздражает. Таймеры рандомно мерцают каждую секунду, как будто не успевают прорисовываться.
`DoubleBuffered` - не помогло.

Дополнение :
По подписки на `SubscriptionsWatcher` дергается метод :

```
public void ToUpdateInfoToDockInfoTable()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.ReadDockState", connection))
        {
            using (DockInfoTableDB = new DataTable())
            {
                DockInfoTableDB.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

                for (int i = 0; i < DockInfoTableDB.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string doorNumber =  DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["doorNumber"].ToString();
                    string truckNumber = DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["truckNumber"].ToString();
                    string phoneNumber = DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["phoneNumber"].ToString();

                    if (allDocs.Count < 32)
                    {
                        allDocs.Add(new Loads(doorNumber, truckNumber, phoneNumber));
                        ToAddControlsPanelDocks(allDocs[i].Load);
                    }

                    allDocs[i].ToChangeCarNumber(truckNumber);
                    allDocs[i].ToChangePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                    allDocs[i].PhoneStatus = (int)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["phoneStatus"];
                    allDocs[i].ConstantsTable = ConstantsTableDB;

                    int idEvent =   (int)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["idEvent"];

                    if (allDocs[i].IdEvent != idEvent && allDocs[i].IdEvent > 0)
                    {
                        allDocs[i].PhoneStatus = 0;
                    }

                    DateTime ? startTimeAction;

                    switch (idEvent)
                    {
                        case 1: //White color, dock is empty
                            startTimeAction = (DateTime)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["DateTimeLastActionWithDock"];
                            break;
                        case 2: // Green color, appointed to dock, but vehicle not at dock
                            startTimeAction = (DateTime)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["appointToDock"];
                            break;
                        case 3: //Yellow color, vehicle at dock, but loading not started
                            startTimeAction = (DateTime)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["DateTimeLastActionWithDock"];
                            break;
                        case 4: //Red color, loading started but not finished
                            startTimeAction = (DateTime)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["startOfLoading"];
                            break;
                        case 5: //Blue color, vehicle is full, but not departed out dock
                            startTimeAction = (DateTime)DockInfoTableDB.Rows[i]["finishOfLoading"];
                            break;
                        default:
                            startTimeAction = null;
                            break;
                    }

                    allDocs[i].StartTimeFormLastAction = startTimeAction;
                    allDocs[i].ToChangeHeaderColor(idEvent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Так же этот метод запускается во время первого запуска в `Form_Load`. По сути метод вычитывает данные из БД и заполняет информацией несколько `label` на форме. В этом же методе изменяется поле `allDocs[i].StartTimeFormLastAction`, на которое опирается выше указанный метод `ToUpdateTimer(TimeSpan newTime)`.

```
private void ToAddControlsPanelDocks(TableLayoutPanel docks)
{
    if (panelDocs.InvokeRequired)
    {
        panelDocs.BeginInvoke(new panelDocksDelegate(ToAddControlsPanelDocks), new object[] { docks });
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        panelDocs.Controls.Add(docks);
    }
}
```

Вроде бы всё.

Comment: Попробуй каждый контрол обновлять в отдельном своем потоке

Comment: Нечему тут мерцать. Нужно больше информации.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сделал таймер не 1, а у каждого элемента `allDocs[i]` свой, мерцания все равно остались, но намного меньше. Я даже не знаю чем дополнить. И не знаю куда копать(

Comment: Набросал [пример](https://pastebin.com/LYp6CgBE) с 32-мя лейблами. Обновляются каждую секунду. Ничего не мерцает. Нужно больше информации (кода), чтобы понять причину.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov действительно практически все также, сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov дополнил

Comment: _По подписки на SubscriptionsWatcher дергается метод :_ - вот это непонятно. Что за подписка? Что за вотчер? Когда именно дёргается метод? Вероятно, он вызывается часто, обращения к БД медленные, вот всё и тормозит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov он вызывается когда происходят изменения в БД, ориентировочно раз в минуту. Но если его отключить, на мерцание это не влияет. Это `SqlDependency`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обновлять значение контролов (label) в событии формы (контрола) onPaint.

А в таймере вызывайте перерисовку форму: this.invalidate();